# Designing tables for job offers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Let's say i have 3 tables:

```
employers : id | name | ...

workers: id | name | ...

jobs : id | description | employer_id | ...
```

I want the employer to be able to make a job offer to several workers, so that the first worker to accept an offer gets the job. I am struggling designing a table to tackle that problem.

I came up with a table like this:

```
 offers: id | job_id | worker_id | status
```

*job_id* and *worker_id* would be a fk referencing respectively *jobs* and *workers*.
The status is an ENUM with **`"accepted", "pending" and "closed" as possible values. (the default value is "pending")`**

The idea here is that when a worker accepts an offer, the status of the corresponding row in *offers* is set to "accepted" and the statuses of the other offers (about the same job) are set to "closed".

I think this could work, but still want to ask if you guys think this is a good and effective solution. If not, what would be a better solution.

Thanks

Note: This is my first time trying to design a database. Also, this is not a homework. I am just working on a small project with some friends.

Comment: Posting your database homework questions is not a good way to get a tech job.  Not my downvotes though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So, is this a common homework question, or how do you come to this conclusion? I fail to see why the question got so many downvotes, apart from that it could be more on point.

Comment: @fancyPants I didn't downvote it.

Comment: I didn't either, but could it be that your comment attracts the downvotes?

Comment: @fancyPants People should not be basing their vote decisions on anyone's comments.

Comment: Yeah, they shouldn't, but I wouldn't be surprised if some still would.

Comment: This could work yes. Are you after alternative solutions or just a simple yes/no answer to whether or not the solution will work?

Comment: @Shy To clarify, when a job is offered to 5 workers, the offers table will have 5 entries, right?

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen That is the only solution I could think of. So I am really interested in alternatives. Thanks

Comment: @fancyPants yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work, yes. A problem you face though, is that you have to ensure, that only one of the workers accepts the job, not two at the same time.

In your case you would this the following way:

```
UPDATE offers o 
SET status = 'accepted' 
WHERE job_id = x 
AND worker_id = y
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM offers WHERE job_id = o.job_id AND status = 'accepted');
```

Of course there are other designs imaginable, too. But this really depends on what you want to achieve.
For example, you could get rid of the status field entirely, when the difference between `pending` and `closed` is not really important to you. 
Then you could simply store in `offers` which workers the job was offered to and in the jobs table you could have a column `accepted_by`.